# Дождаться загрузки страницы C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Программа заходит на сайт, ищет кнопку авторизации, вводит логин и пароль, нажимает Enter, а далее необходимо дождаться, пока загрузится новая страница, и уже на ней найти следующую кнопку.

```
webElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("fancybox"));  //  Находим элемент на станице по имени класса 
webElement.Click();

webElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("p_login"));  //  Находим поле для ввода логина
webElement.SendKeys(login);  //  Вводим сохраненный логин

webElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("p_pass"));  //  Находим поле для ввода пароля
webElement.SendKeys(password + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);  //  Вводим пароль и нажимаем Enter
```

Нужно написать какую-то функцию, которая будет ждать загрузки страницы, потому что поиск следующей кнопки сразу выдает исключение. Вот код поиска:

```
webElement = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Преподавателю"));
webElement.Click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Уверен, что здесь необходимо явное ожидание элемента. Отсюда сразу могу предложить такое (тут, правда, на java, но не вижу большой разницы):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElement(By.PartialLinkText("Преподавателю")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.PartialLinkText("Преподавателю")));
```

Ну а ещё, конечно, полезная статеечка: http://barancev.github.io/slow-loading-pages/

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Пока использовал driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); исключение вылетать перестало. Я так понимаю, что в течении указанного времени происходит поиск элемента. Это, конечно, лучше, чем Thread.Sleep(), но тоже не оптимально)

Comment: @АмирЗакиров, то, что вы использовали - это неявное ожидание. То, что я предложил - явное ожидание. Обязательно погуглите, почитайте.